# MPI Overlapping using C language to produce array summation

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I was learning about MPI programing and came across following stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660848/how-to-pass-2d-array-in-mpi-and-create-a-dynamic-tag-value-using-c-language/32664335#32664335). I am using this same "answered" example to calculate the sum of each row in a way that it will increase the overlapping. This is a 2 by 3 array and I want to calculate the sum as soon as these array elements reach `MPI_Irecv`. I have edited my code between `MPI_Irecv` and `MPI_Wait` to start calculating as soon as array elements become available. But when I run the code, it seems like the way I called `MPI_Test` not working properly. If you can resolve this with an example, I would really appreciate it.

Using `mpirun -np 3 test` 0th rank will generate array elements. 1st and 2nd ranks will calculate the sum

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        int world_rank;
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
        int world_size;
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);        
        int tag = 1;        
        int arr[2][3]; 
        MPI_Request request;
        MPI_Status status;
        int source = 0;
        int dest;
        int flag;

        printf ("\n--Current Rank: %d\n", world_rank);
        //To handle the number of process received by the user will be handled here later
        if (world_rank == 0)
        {
            int i = 1;
            int a, b, x, y;

            printf("* Rank 0 excecuting\n");
            for(x=0; x<2; x++)//Generating the whole 2 by 3  2D array
            {   
                i++;
                for ( y = 0; y < 3; y++ )
                {
                    arr[x][y] = i;//first row contain all 2 
                }                 //second row contain all 3
            }

            int subarray_index;
            for(subarray_index=0; subarray_index < 2; subarray_index++)
            {
                dest = subarray_index%(world_size - 1) + 1;     
                tag = subarray_index;
                MPI_Isend(&arr[subarray_index][0], 3, MPI_INT, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            int a, b;                   
            for(b=0; b<2/(world_size-1); b++)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                int i;                
                int my_offset = world_rank-1;
                tag = b*(world_size-1) + my_offset;
                int subarray = b;
                MPI_Irecv(&arr[subarray][0], 3, MPI_INT, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
                MPI_Test(&request, &flag, &status);//I think there may be an error at MPI_Test too
                while (flag != 1)
                {
                    MPI_Test(&request, &flag, &status); 
                    for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
                    {   
                        //if(!arr[subarray][i])//want to wait till I recive actual array elements
                        //{//This need to start calculating as soon as array element become avilable 
                            printf("%d) arr[subarray][i]:%d at rank %d\n", tag, arr[subarray][i], world_rank);
                            sum = arr[subarray][i]+sum;
                        //}
                    }
                }                
                printf("\nSum is: %d at rank: %d and tag is:%d\n", sum, world_rank, tag);
                MPI_Wait (&request, &status); 
            }           
        }
        MPI_Finalize();
}
```

When I type in `mpirun -np 3 test` Answer should be "Sum is 6" and "Sum is 9"

```
--Current Rank: 2
1) arr[subarray][i]:40896 at rank 2
1) arr[subarray][i]:32767 at rank 2
1) arr[subarray][i]:617513272 at rank 2
1) arr[subarray][i]:40896 at rank 2
1) arr[subarray][i]:32767 at rank 2
1) arr[subarray][i]:617513272 at rank 2
1) arr[subarray][i]:40896 at rank 2
1) arr[subarray][i]:32767 at rank 2
1) arr[subarray][i]:617513272 at rank 2 //all above arr element shows it's empty
1) arr[subarray][i]:3 at rank 2 //following three values are correct and these
1) arr[subarray][i]:3 at rank 2 //are the only three that need to use for summing
1) arr[subarray][i]:3 at rank 2

Sum is: 1909043312 at rank: 2 and tag is:1

--Current Rank: 0
* Rank 0 excecuting

--Current Rank: 1 //here I don't get arr element values as above

Sum is: 0 at rank: 1 and tag is:0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your question is. But from your description, I'd deduce that process 1 reaches `MPI_Test` when the message is already received. Thus, `flag` is already set and the loop is never entered.

On rank 2 on the other hand you are adding up uninitialized values, due to performing the summation unconditionally while waiting on the message to be received.

You can do the summation only after the message is received. That is, when the flag is set, which is after your while loop and basically voids your whole construct, as you could just do:

```
MPI_Irecv(&arr[subarray][0], 3, MPI_INT, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
MPI_Wait (&request, &status);
```

The wait will return as soon as the message becomes available, which is the point of `MPI_Wait`. Now, the above is basically equivalent to a blocking `MPI_Recv`.

On the other hand, you are to wait on the communication to finish at some point also on the sending side. There you need individual requests for each `MPI_Isend`. Then you can make use of `MPI_Waitall` after your sending loop.

Thus, you might have wanted something like this (with a blocking receive):

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        int world_rank;
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
        int world_size;
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
        int tag = 1;
        int arr[2][3];
        MPI_Request request[2];
        int source = 0;
        int dest;
        int flag;

        printf ("\n--Current Rank: %d\n", world_rank);
        //To handle the number of process received by the user will be handled here later
        if (world_rank == 0)
        {
            int i = 1;
            int a, b, x, y;
            MPI_Status status[2];

            printf("* Rank 0 excecuting\n");
            for(x=0; x<2; x++)//Generating the whole 2 by 3  2D array
            {
                i++;
                for ( y = 0; y < 3; y++ )
                {
                    arr[x][y] = i;//first row contain all 2 
                }                 //second row contain all 3
                dest = x%(world_size - 1) + 1;
                tag = x;
                MPI_Isend(&arr[x][0], 3, MPI_INT, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[x]);
            }

            MPI_Waitall(2, &request[0], &status[0]);

        }
        else
        {
            int a, b;
            MPI_Status status;

            for(b=0; b<2/(world_size-1); b++)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                int i;
                int my_offset = world_rank-1;
                tag = b*(world_size-1) + my_offset;
                int subarray = b;
                MPI_Recv(&arr[subarray][0], 3, MPI_INT, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
                {
                    //if(!arr[subarray][i])//want to wait till I recive actual array elements
                    //{//This need to start calculating as soon as array element become avilable 
                        printf("%d) arr[subarray][i]:%d at rank %d\n", tag, arr[subarray][i], world_rank);
                        sum = arr[subarray][i]+sum;
                    //}
                }
                printf("\nSum is: %d at rank: %d and tag is:%d\n", sum, world_rank, tag);
            }
        }
        MPI_Finalize();
}
```

This sends off the values as soon as possible, and acts on the other side on the rows as soon as they are received. You might still want to post multiple receives on the receiving side, if that process is to process multiple rows, but in this case you need again an array of requests, and you would use `MPI_Waitany` or `MPI_Waitsome` to act on received messages as soon as possible.

Here is the receiving part with `MPI_Waitany`:

```
{
    int a, b;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Request request[2/(world_size-1)];

    for(b=0; b<2/(world_size-1); b++)
    {
        int my_offset = world_rank-1;
        tag = b*(world_size-1) + my_offset;
        int subarray = b;
        MPI_Irecv(&arr[subarray][0], 3, MPI_INT, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[b]);
    }
    for(b=0; b<2/(world_size-1); b++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int i;
        MPI_Waitany(2/(world_size-1), &request[0], &a, &status);
        for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
                printf("%d) arr[subarray][i]:%d at rank %d\n", status.MPI_TAG, arr[a][i], world_rank);
                sum = arr[a][i]+sum;
        }
        printf("\nSum is: %d at rank: %d and tag is:%d\n", sum, world_rank, status.MPI_TAG);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer and explaining everything in details. You are the best

Comment: @Learner_51 Glad it helped you. Have fun.